# In what order are the elements of a List accessed

Tags: java, list, listiterator

I am looking at lists and ordering in Java.  According to the documentation a `List` is an ordered list of Objects and when the Objects are standard class such as `String`, `Integer` it will use a standard comparator to do the comparison.  A few questions jump to mind.

1. If your list of some arbitrary object (not a standard class) do you have to implement the `Comparator` interface, or will it rely on `toString()`?
2. Do you have to use a ListIterator to traverse the list in the order you require?

Looking at the documentation elements are added to the list at the end and thus will not be in order unless you sort it or use the ListIterator.

Answer (score 3):

Items added to a `List` are stored in the order they are entered (so it's insertion order). If you want to sort a `List` you can use [`Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) or the `Collections.sort(List)` method.

Answer (score 2):

**Ordered != Sorted**

Ordered means that the elements in the structure have a determined order (given by insertion).
`Set`s are unordered, `List`s are ordered, `LinkedHashSet` is ordered, and so on...

If you want the list to have in a specific order, determined by

- the natural order (`implements Comparable`) or
- a provivided order (`implements Comparator`),

you have to **sort** it (see `Collections.sort()`).

Answer (score 2):

First, I am afraid that you are confusing with *ordered* and *sorted* terms. "Ordered" does not mean that the elements are sorted according to any criteria. It just means that elements order is predictable. In case of lists the order is dictated by list index and, for example, if you add 5 elements using `add()` method you will then iterate over the list and get the elements in the same order.

Sorted means that elements may be re-arranged (sorted) using one of available methods (e.g. `Collections.sort()`). In this case comparator is relevant.

Concerning the "standard" and non standard classes. Neither `String` nor `Integer` does not have any privileges in terms of sorting. Additionally to `Comparator` interface JDK provides `Comparable` interface implemented by both `String` and `Integer`. This is the reason that String and Interger lists can be sorted in natural order. Please take a look on javadoc of mentioned interfaces for more details. You can make your class to implement `Comparable` and enjoy the same features.

Neither `Comparator` nor `Comparable` do not relate to `toString()` and although it can be used when implementing both it is highly not recommended.

`ListIterator` provides more methods relatively to `Iterator`. For example you can traverse list backwards. You should choose iterator type according to your needs. Although since java 5 is released (~10 years ago) the iterators are needed more seldom because all collections implement `Iterable` that can be directly used in `for` loops. Iteraters are needed basically if you want to remove elements during iteration. BTW starting from Java 8 that was released several months ago `List.forEach()` will be used more and more, so iterators will become even less popular.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, now it makes sense.  If I wish to have my objects in a specific order I will have to sort which means I need to implement comparator so I can compare items.

Comment: Correct. `Comparator` or `Comparable`

Comment: Just as an aside, I am stuck with Java 7 as the application I am writing extensions for has Java 7 bundled in it and I wish to maintain compatability.

Answer (score 0):

`a List is an ordered list of Objects` The "ordered" here means insertion order.

if you want to sort the list in certain order, you have to provide the `Comparator` or make your elements implement `Comparable`. you can call `Collectoins class's:`

`public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)`

or

`public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`

If you just want to go through your list, a normal `Iterator` is enough. while, `ListIterator` provides more funtionality, like:

- backwards iteration
- get the index of pre/next element

Comment: Thanks also, please see my comment to AlexR.